# Crystal report showing one column same at Multiple rows

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have wrote an query in vb.net to show at crystal report but one columns name  Customer.Name showing at report same at all rows here my query and code

```
Dim rpt As New rptSales2 'The report you created.
        Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
        Dim MyCommand, MyCommand1 As New SqlCommand()
        Dim myDA, myDA1 As New SqlDataAdapter()
        Dim myDS, myDS1 As New DataSet 'The DataSet you created.
        myConnection = New SqlConnection(cs)
        MyCommand.Connection = myConnection
        MyCommand1.Connection = myConnection
        MyCommand.CommandText = "select invoiceinfo.Inv_ID, invoiceinfo.InvoiceNo,invoiceinfo.InvoiceDate, Customer.Name, sum(InvoiceInfo.GrandTotal)-sum(invoiceinfo.prevdue) as grandtotal, sum(invoiceinfo.TotalPaid) as totalpaid,ISNULL(sum(Balance),0)-ISNULL(sum(prevdue),0) as currentdue,ISNULL(sum(prevdue),0) as prevdue,sum(invoiceinfo.Balance) as Balance from InvoiceInfo inner join Customer on InvoiceInfo.CustomerID = Customer.ID where InvoiceDate between @d1 and @d2 group by invoiceinfo.InvoiceDate,invoiceinfo.InvoiceNo,Customer.Name,InvoiceInfo.TotalPaid,invoiceinfo.Inv_ID"

        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Date").Value = dtpDateFrom.Value.Date
        MyCommand.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, "Date").Value = dtpDateTo.Value.Date
        MyCommand1.CommandText = "SELECT * from Company"
        MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        MyCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand
        myDA1.SelectCommand = MyCommand1
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "InvoiceInfo")
        myDA.Fill(myDS, "Customer")
        myDA1.Fill(myDS, "Company")
```

here the sql query `select invoiceinfo.Inv_ID, invoiceinfo.InvoiceNo,invoiceinfo.InvoiceDate, Customer.Name, sum(InvoiceInfo.GrandTotal)-sum(invoiceinfo.prevdue) as grandtotal, sum(invoiceinfo.TotalPaid) as totalpaid,ISNULL(sum(Balance),0)-ISNULL(sum(prevdue),0) as currentdue,ISNULL(sum(prevdue),0) as prevdue,sum(invoiceinfo.Balance) as Balance from InvoiceInfo inner join Customer on InvoiceInfo.CustomerID = Customer.ID where InvoiceDate between @d1 and @d2 group by invoiceinfo.InvoiceDate,invoiceinfo.InvoiceNo,Customer.Name,InvoiceInfo.TotalPaid,invoiceinfo.Inv_ID`
But the query showing good at sql server managment studio query

here the screen shot for both at crystal report and sql server managment studio

https://gyazo.com/569dad19a7957f35eb449fd45adf1177
https://gyazo.com/f8b6b8b56ab05c4c54a9b49e60ee6cae

Please help me at this point

Comment: May you post a screen shot of the crystal report design?

Comment: Yes sue here the screenshot for crystal report design
https://gyazo.com/fc7558ee5ea4ac7b6ac48b7cfcbd6eab

Comment: It does not make sense for me, but looks like the client join is not the expected result. Could you copy the Inv_ID and Name (customer name) to the details session and post the screenshot of the result?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the SQL MS screenshot, what I can infer is that you do not require a group in your report in the first place,try removing the group and place your fields in the detail section.It should work just fine.